# can we just declare constructor in parent class and define it in another class in java?

Tags: java, constructor

```
class Rad{
    public double p=10,a;
    Rad();

}

    class Area{
        Rad(){
        a=3.14*p*p;
        System.out.println(a); 
    }
        public static void main(String args[]){
            Rad o=new Rad();
        }

    }
```

SOMETHING LIKE THIS BUT IT'S NOT WORKING;CAN I GET PROVIDED WITH SOLUTION||||

Comment: Look in to `super()`.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible constructors in `Area` are `Area` constructors, but the empty `Area` constructor overrides the empty `Rad` constructor (if `Area` is a subclass of `Rad`). Something like,

```
class Rad {
    public double p = 10, a;

    protected Rad() { // <-- only visible to subclasses.
    }
}
```

Also, I wouldn't `print` in the constructor; instead override `toString` and print the instance you have created. Something like,

```
class Area extends Rad { // <-- a subclass of Rad.
    public Area() {
        a = Math.PI * p * p;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(a);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Rad o = new Rad();
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: really thankful for ur help,,,and pardon if question ws too silly

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot...Constructors must be defined in their own class...not their parent's and not their children's